# .sink method from Combine not working on iOS 13.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, combine, ios13.3

I'm using sink method to call function when variable value changed.
Code working on iOS 13.2.2 but not on iOS 13.3. Function segmentedChanged not called when segmentedSelected variable changed.

```
public class ChooseViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var segmentedSelected = Int()


    init() {
        _ = $segmentedSelected
                .debounce(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                .sink(receiveValue: self.segmentedChanged(indexValue:))

    }

    func segmentedChanged(indexValue segIndex: Int) {
      print(segIndex)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This might be due to fixed releasing of cancelable (just an assumption). Try the following

```
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

init() {
    $segmentedSelected
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: self.segmentedChanged(indexValue:))
            .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```